# Make a LDAP client communicate to multiple LDAP servers/have a failover?

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, ldap, openldap, failover

I'm setting up a few Ubuntu servers where the users authenticate against my school's Active Directory server to log in using libnss-LDAP client. However, there are some users that aren't in that AD database and would need access. While having those users be local users in each machine is an option, is it possible to setup another open-LDAP server containing only those users and use it as a failover such that the machines (ldap clients) look into it in case the user wasn't found in the school's AD server.

I tried looking into possible ldap configuration to make LDAP client communicate to multiple LDAP servers, or designate a failover LDAP server in case authentication fails due to user not existing, but haven't found any yet.